# Backup a remote database, from my machine, to another server (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, backup, remote

I'm trying to backup a database, of a remote server, from my machine, to another server.

```
 SERVER1   >>>  BACKUPSERVER
      \             /
       \           /   
        \         /
         My Machine
```

I have `SERVER1` with some databases. I'm connected on it from my machine, and I'm using:

```
BACKUP DATABASE X 
TO DISK ='BACKUPSERVER\Database.bak'
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'BACKUPSERVER\BACKUP LOCAL'.
>   Operating system error 1265(The system detected a possible attempt to
>   compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server
>   that authenticated you.).

OBS: I will not change anything, because I contact the guys from infrastructure, and told them to change the `Service Login` (just to test), and they told me that they will migrate this server to another one and I should not be worried about it (I'm DBA jr, so I'm learning the server maping from here).

But I'm curious about that error. And if a face this again, how could I solve it?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This problem occurs because the network firewall filters Kerberos traffic.
>
> To resolve this problem, configure the network firewall so that TCP port 88 and UDP port 88 are not blocked for either domain.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938457

Sorry for just quoting...

Another thing to check is to make sure that your Service Startup account for SQL Server has the rights to access the file share that you are backing up to.

In SQL Server Configuration in the instance name > Properties > Log On > Log On as Account Type.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to connect the backupserver, connected on the server1. I blocked me for permissions reasons. So this is the problem.  Thanks friend.